# oauth permission unknown issue in rspec for linkedin api

Tags: oauth, rspec

when I am call in spec, the get :authenticate_linkedin_login method of controller getting error the oauth:problem permission unknown.

****spec file.****

describe  LinkedinProfileController do

include LinkedinStubs

before(:each) do

```
@temp = Factory(:worker)
```

controller.stub(:authenticate_user!)

```
controller.stub!(:current_user).and_return(@temp)

 WebMock.allow_net_connect!(:net_http_connect_on_start => true)
```

end

describe "/login" do

it "should redirect to linkedin authorization url" do

```
   stub_oauth_request_token!

   get :linkedin_login

   session[:rtoken].should == 't'

   session[:rsecret].should == 's'

  response.location.should =~ /www.linkedin.com/

 response.should be_redirect   #request authorize url
```

end

end

```
describe "/authenticate_linkedin_login" do
 it "should be authorize_from_request" do
  get :authenticate_linkedin_login,:oauth_verifier=>'12345'
```

****Controller****
class LinkedinProfileController < ApplicationController

before_filter :authenticate_worker!

def linkedin_login
     client = LinkedIn::Client.new('lrkf3ol8f91k','OGJbzX3lKNSOxNwT')

```
  request_token = client.request_token(:oauth_callback => "http://#{request.host_with_port}/authenticate_linkedin_login")

    session[:rtoken] = request_token.token

    session[:rsecret] = request_token.secret

    redirect_to client.request_token.authorize_url
end
```

def authenticate_linkedin_login

```
    client = LinkedIn::Client.new('lrkf3ol8f91k','OGJbzX3lKNSOxNwT')
       if session[:atoken].nil?

        pin = params[:oauth_verifier]

        atoken, asecret = client.authorize_from_request(session[:rtoken], session[:rsecret], pin)

        session[:atoken] = atoken

        session[:asecret] = asecret
    else
```

client.authorize_from_access(session[:atoken], session[:asecret])
        end